# Using .children() to gather data-values

Tags: jquery, html, children

HTML:

```
<div class="master">
  <div class='example' data-value="one">One</div>
  <div class='example' data-value="two">Two</div>
  <div class='example' data-value="three">Three</div>
</div>
```

Here is my jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b41wxebq/5/

As you'll see, an alert of 'one' is shown and not 'one,two,three'. Why is that? How can I capture all the data-values of the parent 'master'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to iterate through them and `alert` each time, or you can use `.map` to get an array of the values:

```
var dataVals = $("div.master div.example").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("value");
}).get();

console.log(dataVals); //['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Comment: +1 If it's just attributes and not data **set** with `data()`, that `return` line can be a bit more efficient:  `return this.getAttribute("data-value");` (no need to wrap, read the attributes, and *duplicate* their data to the jQuery `data` cache if all we want to do is read the attributes). Of course, with three elements, it's not like it matters...

Answer (score 1):

try this, you can use `each`funcion also, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b41wxebq/6/)

```
 var data_value=[];
   $("div.master div.example").each(function() {
        data_value.push($(this).attr("data-value"));
     });
 alert(data_value);
```